# Exclude the content before "the more" on single posts

Tags: read-more

I have a post with text then "the more" then text after that.

The teaser before the more displays on the archive page, but I don't want to display it on my single post page, only the text after the more should appear.

How do I do this?

i.e

This is my text before the more don't show it.

--The More--

Text after the more to be displayed on single page.

Comment: Curious why you wouldn't simply use a manual excerpt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably looking at something like [`get_extended()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_extended). It returns the content in an array with the following key=>value pairs

- `main` => The content before the more tag
- `extended` => The content after the more tag
- `more_text` => The custom read more text

So you would want to do the following in your single post page inside the loop

```
$content  = get_extended( $post->post_content );
$extended = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content['extended'] );
echo $extended;
```

Comment: Okay, learned something new again :D Deleted my answer, as your one's better :)

Comment: @fischi As I always say, one is never too old or too ugly to learn something new. I know I learn a lot everyday from others on this site as well. ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about get_extended(). This piece of code isn't working for me, not sure why, but I managed to use it find something that did.

Comment: What do you mean by not working

Comment: Sorry I mean it is not echoing out any content.

Comment: Okay I've been using WordPress for 10 years and I did not know this function existed. It's even defined *right* above `get_post`. http://i.imgur.com/tMuQON3.gif

Comment: @MrFox It should work fine now. For some crappy reason, `get_the_content()` don't work, only `$post->post_content`

Comment: @TheDeadMedic we always learn as we go along. Just also found out that we need to pass raw post content to `get_extended()`, `get_the_content()` just don't work. Strange

Comment: @MrFox My pleasure. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me:

```
$aftermore = 3 + strpos($post->post_content, '-->');
$devcontent = substr($post->post_content,$aftermore);
echo wpautop($devcontent);?>
endif;
```